# How can I run LAMMPS in python in Windows 10?

Tags: python, linux, installation, lammps

I'm having trouble in trying to use this software as a python library. The instructions that appear in the LAMMPS' site (https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Python_head.html) seem to meant to be for Linux OS and I have Windows, so it's kinda hard for me to understand them.

Comment: from lammps import lammps

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Win10 x64 bit version of LAMMPS from here.
https://rpm.lammps.org/windows/64bit/ and refer for LAMMPS Python module
https://packages.lammps.org/windows.html